# Auto-subdivide path

Tags: animation, keyframes

*I created a simple animation of an airplane flying around things. I noticed that the airplane's speed is not constant, it changes over time. Is there any way that I can make this speed constant?
Note: I'm not asking to make the speed between two keyframes constant (which can be done by using the graph editor and the keyframe's interpolations) but how to make the whole animation (with many keyframes) happen at a constant pace.*

**Update:** I chose to recreate the animation using a path (as this makes things such as smooth curves a lot easier). I noticed that when using the `Follow Path` Constraint, the object's speed is determined by how many "Subdivisions" there are in each segment of the path.

I want the object to have a constant speed so is there any way to make the "subdivision density" the same for all segments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the simplest way to keep a constant speed over the course of the animation is to simply keyframe the `Offset` value in the Follow path constraint of the object. You can insert two keyframes so that it goes from 0 to 1 and adjust the interpolation to be linear.

Answer (score 1):

When you select *all* of the keyframes in the graph editor, and press <kbd>T</kbd> to adjust the keyframes' interpolations, it adjusts all of them, not just two. However, if that does not work, you may have to re-keyframe the animation of the airplane, because the animation speed itself in the keyframes is different. You can't automatically make the animation keyframes constant, if that is what you are asking.

If your animation is lagging, it may also give an appearance of slowing down on some keyframes, but that is unlikely.